# DC adapter power output equation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

This question may sound senseless but I am novice, just looking for clarification. My Cordless phone has a Wall wart AC Power Adapter rated at 9v 500mAh. As far as replacement is concerned, does output power only matters or we have to be specific with ratings also? Like a 4.5V 1A adapter output will also be 4.5W as original rating. I have read in this forum that higher current rating may not matter but higher voltage may damage. Also, I have heard that SMPS based supplies senses the actual load and outputs accordingly. Please correct me.

Comment: Yes both can supply same power but only into the matching load and V may be too low for phone charger. SMPS are regulated and current limited.  unregulated wall transformer rectifiers are limited in current but voltage drops to rated value at full current.

Answer (score 0):

To replace your cordless phone adaptor, you need an adaptor rated for 9 volts, and 500 mA (Not mAh!) or more.

The adaptor voltage must match the phone's requirements, but the adaptor's power or current rating may be greater thant the phone's requirements - the phone will only draw the current it requires.

(mAh is a specification for the amount of energy that can be stored ini a battery, and has little relation to the current the battery can deliver.  It is meaningless when used for power supplies.)

Comment: ... unless you have a power supply that self-destructs after one hour at full load, or three hours at 1/3 of full load, of course.